# How can I close a form from another form?

Tags: lazarus

Let's say I have two forms `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` contains two buttons, one that creates and displays `Form2` and a button to close `Form2`.

To create `Form2` I use:

```
Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
Form2.Show;
```

How do I close `Form2` from `Form1`?

Comment: tutorial seeking?

Comment: @ZF007 Well, some kind of, had completely missed nil. Has not worked with Pascal code for a while.

Comment: In comment to the answer you say: *I had completely missed putting form to NIL, hence I got the error message on the second creation of the form.* Yet you did not think this would be important to mention in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `Close` method of the other form:

```
Form2.Close;
```

Or if you want to destroy the object:

```
Form2.Free;
```

Or if you merely want to hide it:

```
Form2.Hide;
```

If the button that shows the form also creates it, then you need to make sure that you don't leak instances of the form. Imagine clicking that button multiple times, and making multiple instances of the form.

So perhaps you want code like this to create and show the form:

```
if not Assigned(Form2) then
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
Form2.Show;
```

and code like this to close and destroy it:

```
Form2.Free;
Form2 := nil;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had completely missed putting form to NIL, hence I got the error message on the second creation of the form.
Now it works prefect!